# when two Topologies are equal

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Suppose we have two topologies on the same set. Can we say that two topologies are equal if we show that neighborhood of some arbitrary point x in one topology is contained in the neighborhood of the same point x in another topology?
And can topologies be equal if  subbasis for one topology  contain in subbasis for another topology?

Comment: Then all topologies are equal to the trivial topology: every point has only one neighbourhood, the whole set itself.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal{T_1},\mathcal{T_2}$ two topologies on a set $X$

Then $\mathcal{T_1} \subseteq \mathcal{T_2}$ if every open set in $X$ with respect to $\mathcal{T_1}$ is open in $X$ with respect to  $\mathcal{T_2}$.

What do you conclude from that?

Comment: i understand this. but i am confused with subbasis contiantment.